# Use of RREF pin on USB hub IC

Tags: integrated-circuit, usb-hub

I have a problem concerning the realization of a USB 3.0 hub using the integrated circuit UPD720201K8-711-BAC-A. This concerns pin 33 called RREF.

In the [documentation](https://4donline.ihs.com/images/VipMasterIC/IC/RNCC/RNCCS17404/RNCCS17404-1.pdf?hkey=52A5661711E402568146F3353EA87419) I can't find any explanation on how it works and being a beginner, I don't know at all what I should do with it.

It would be great if someone could help me find out how and to what I should connect this pin.

Comment: The link to the datasheet requires a log in.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot! I changed the link, here is one accessible without the need to log in.

Comment: The datasheet does not tell what to do with it. The data sheet does not tell many other things as well how to use the chip. That information will therefore be in other document than the datasheet. Find the other documents that include examples and instructions how to use the chip.

Comment: The datasheet manual explains only that it is "used" by USB2 and that it is a "resistance reference connection". §2.2 Analog Signal.

Comment: You're right @Justme, I found a more complete datasheet and there is all the information I needed, thank you!